# Count Values From Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a script in SQL Server that will count values under a column but I want it to still report missing values not counted.

Currently, I have the following setup with a group by, but it cuts the results in half:

```
select count(ID) as Count, Building, ID
from table
group by Building, ID
```

I want my output to show the count per ID as well as null values if there was nothing to count per ID.

```
Building  ID
1234      1
1234      2
4567      3
4567      4
8910      5
0         6

Want the Output To Be:
Building  ID Count
1234       1   2
1234       2   2
4567       3   2
4567       4   2
8910       5   1
0          6   0
```

The total population is 200,000.  I want to see 200,000 records with the total counts per name or null values.  When I run the above script, I obtain 1's per record.

Example: If ID 1 has a count of 2 and ID 2 has a count of 2, I want both IDs to show up as separate counts per ID.

Comment: Edit your question and (1) tag with the database you are using; (2) show sample data; (3) show desired results.  "Report missing values not counted" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the count from a sub-query and then join that sub-query

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN t1.building is null THEN 0
   ELSE t1.building END AS Building,
   t1.id, 
   CASE WHEN t1.building is null THEN 0
   ELSE t2.count END AS Count
FROM table t1
JOIN (SELECT building, COUNT(*) as count 
      FROM table 
      GROUP BY building) AS t2 ON t2.building = t1.building OR (t2.building is null AND t1.building is null)
```

Comment: While this query works, I do not want to count null values.  I want them to show up as 0's per ID that has a null value for building.

Comment: Then we need to use CASE WHEN, I'll update the answer

Comment: I'm still not getting 0's for id's where there is no building number.  I do not want to count the null values for 0.  I want them to appear per ID that doesn't have a building number.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry, you need to use the second join in my answer, I forgot to change that, although it says in the text to use that for null values... I make another update

Answer (score -1):

try

```
select count(name) as Count, ID, Building
from table
group by ID, Building
```

Comment: How is this different that the statement shown in the question?